# Is this a sensible deconvolution procedure?

Tags: convolution

I'm working with deconvolution a lot, in situations that naturally give me

- a long series of observations O in the presence of both noise N and effect E
- a long series of observations C from a control situation where only N is present

and I want to estimate the distribution of E.

Thus O is a convolution of C by E, I have O and C and want to deconvolve O to get E.

A simple approach to estimating E has occurred to me:

- (assuming for the sake of simplicity that O and C have the same number of observations)
- sort O and C each in ascending order
- then construct a series E' where E'1 = O1-C1 .... E'n = On - Cn
- assuming a good number of observations, then the distribution of E' will be a good estimate of the distribution of E.

Am I right? Is it really as simple as this?

Ultimately I will use the distribution of E obtained by deconvolution as a Bayesian prior to get a point estimate of the amount of E present in each O.

In case it's helpful, here is R code that implements this, with extra complexity to allow for the length of C to vary from the length of O.

```r
empiricalDeconvolve <- function(convolved, base) {
  convolved <- sort(convolved)
  point <- 0
  nextPoint <- 0
  dp <- 0
  output <- c()
  base <- sort(base)
  
  for (i in 1:length(convolved)) {
    point <- 1 + (((i-1)/(length(convolved) - 1))*(length(base)-1))
    dp <- point - trunc(point)
    nextPoint <- trunc(point) + 1
    if (nextPoint > length(base)){nextPoint <- trunc(point);dp <- 0}
    output[i] <- convolved[i] - ((base[trunc(point)]*(1-dp)) + 
                 (base[nextPoint]*(dp)))
  }
  return(output)
}
```

Comment: It is best not to assume people read R code. Do you just want code review? If not, can you provide pseudocode?

Comment: I agree with gung; if you seek to know whether a proposed algorithm would do what you wan, describe the algorithm in concise, simple terms. If you seek code review your post is [off topic](http://stats.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: thanks guys, makes sense. The R code was rather overcomplicated for the question anyway.